# Is there a recommended number of representatives in European democratic countries?

Tags: democracy, parliament

In 2009, Romania [had a referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_parliamentary_reform_referendum,_2009) for reducing the Parliament size to a maximum of 300 seats. However, it was never implemented and in fact, the number of the seats increased to nearly 600.

[This article](https://jakubmarian.com/number-of-seats-in-the-national-parliament-by-country-in-europe-total-per-capita-map/) shows a Europe chart about number of representatives per million people. Romania has indeed one of the largest index (29) in Europe.

**Question:** is there an official recommendation for number of representatives in an European democratic country (e.g. EU country)?

I am thinking of something like [Venice Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venice_Commission#Elections.2C_referendums_and_political_parties) type of recommendation.

[This study](http://voxeu.org/article/optimal-number-representatives-democracy) suggests that an optimal number of representative might exist:

> Having too few members of parliament means parliament is likely to be
>   un-representative, but it seems that having too many makes it easy for
>   vested interests to buy influence. Simple logic suggests that the
>   optimal number of MEPs should be proportional to the square root of
>   the population. **Empirical work suggests that nations with a much
>   higher number of MEPs tend to be plagued by red-tape and corruption.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an optimal size of a parliament?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/364/is-there-an-optimal-size-of-a-parliament)

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - I have narrowed down to Europe to make the question more answerable. Also, referenced data include European countries only, so it makes sense to include only these countries.

Comment: @Bobson - although the question is very similar, I have narrowed my question to Europe only and I am interested in an official recommendation, not an abstract optimal size (ratio).

Comment: "This study suggests that an optimal number of representative might exist" We know that an optimal number must exist, as 1 is too few and the entire population is too many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of an 'official' body to make recommendations, I would have to say "no".

The UN is [pro-democracy](http://www.un.org/en/sections/issues-depth/democracy/), and the EU makes it a [condition of membership](https://ec.europa.eu/neighbourhood-enlargement/policy/conditions-membership_en), but both refrain from making recommendations about exactly which form that democracy should take.

Comment: What about Venice_Commission?[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venice_Commission]. It seems to deal with `Codes of good practice on elections, on referendums and on political parties`. Or it cannot be considered "official"?

Comment: The closest the Venice Commission comes is probably in the [Code of Good Practice in Electoral Matters](http://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/CDL-AD(2002)023rev-e.aspx), where they do explicitly state things like elections should be equal (in the sense that no individual or area is left disenfranchised or under/over-represented), and that distribution of seats should be regularly reviewed, but it makes no recommendations as to the actual size of the representative body.